# How to fine-tune spacy-experimental "en-coreference-web-trf" model on my own custom domain dataset

Tags: python, spacy, fine-tuning, coreference-resolution

I have a custom dataset of conversational data specific to farming domain. The spacy-experimental coreference model [(en-coreference-web-trf)](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/11585) does perform okish in coreference resolution but does not give the required accuracy. So I need to further fine-tune this model on my domain specific data.

I have found this [repo](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/experimental/coref) that allows you train a spacy coref model but I am having trouble following the instructions provided. I have my own custom data, but I do not know in what format it should be to send it for training. The repo says, the project is about training the model using OntoNotes dataset, so I thought I can convert my dataset into the format of OntoNotes, but OntoNotes itself is not a public dataset so I do not its file structure. Also does spacy allow us to finetune the model and not train from scratch? I couldn't find any other resources apart from the specified repo related to my task.

Please do help me with this issue. Thank you.